# Showing PHP database content within a div

Tags: php, sql

I'm setting up a website containing a page that will contain many buttons. I want to be able to click on the button to populate a div with information from a database.

I've adapted some code that I previously had, but it isn't working.

The source javascript and HTML are shown here:

```
<script>
function showBiog(key) {
//alert(key);

      // Get the search value
        var search_value = key

        // This time we're going to grab data from a file to display
        var filename = "functions/biography.php";

        // Send these values
        var posting = $.post(filename, { search_term: search_value });

        // Display this value in our results container
        posting.done(function (data) {
          $("#test_results").empty().append(data);
        });

}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.test {
    background-color: #B32D2F;
    border: thin solid #DBB2B3;
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
}
.testresults {
    background-color: #88B32D;
    border: thin solid #DBB2B3;
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="test" onClick="showBiog(1)"><p>1</p></div>
<div class="test" onClick="showBiog(2)"><p>2</p></div>
<div class="test" onClick="showBiog(3)"><p>3</p></div>
<div class="test" onClick="showBiog(4)"><p>4</p></div>
Results
<div class="testresults" id="test_results"></div>
```

The HTML of biography.php is

```
<body>

<?php if (! $_POST["search_term"]) { ?>
  <div class="err">
      <?php echo $row_Recordset1['firstname']; ?>
  </div>

<?php } else { ?>

<?php echo $row_results['firstname']; }?>

</body>
```

The SQL for results in Dreamweaver is

```
SELECT *
FROM pilots
WHERE key LIKE colname  

with colname $_POST['search_term']
```

Comment: Sidenote: "key" is a MySQL reserved keyword which requires special attention http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - In case you wanted to use "keys" instead, so is that one. By "special attention", I mean wrap that column name in ticks `\`` otherwise, you will get a syntax error.

Comment: Please show us how you are executing the query because that must be where things are going wrong.

Comment: Sorry Jordy, not sure what else I need - can you elaborate

Comment: [Comment #1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901802/showing-php-database-content-within-a-div#comment46062981_28901802) is irrelevant? If so, I'll delete it.

Comment: Fred, I've changed it to keys, still not getting anything in the results box... Am I roughly on the right track though?

Comment: As I said earlier, "keys" is also a reserved keyword. You can't use it, not without special attention to it. Name it to something like "mykey", see what that gives. You need to also check for errors on both the PHP and MySQL side of things.

Comment: So... where are we at; is the question still open, or have my comments helped resolve it? @user2406993

Comment: sadly not no, still playing with things, seeing if I've missed something obvious

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Few things...

1. You may not need "**var search_value = key**" if you are not making any change or addition to it. Simply use "key" in the **$.post** (keep code simple).
2. What is expected to be in "**key**"? Depending on what you are sending, the statement **var posting = $.post(filename, { search_term: search_value });** may break due to JSON structure requirements.

To assure you are sending out the right information to the PHP, you should try something like **$.post(filename, JSON.stringify({ 'search_term': key }) );**

On the PHP side, you can use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to decode JSON data, then process your query.

Just a small personal note and advice: If JSON is not well formed on the POST side, PHP will get nothing, thus it will return nothing. You should always try to *log* or *display* the data received by PHP when writing AJAX calls to assure it was correctly received. Otherwise you may be chasing a bug in the wrong spot. ;)

Comment: Thanks Julio, not quite cracked it, but given me food for thought.